# SSRS - dynamically restructure dataset for chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to build a bar char to show how which drugs are being used to treat certain cases. This is the shape of the data I need to get the chart type I desire.

```
drug    case 1  case 2   case 3
X       100     300      250
Y       200     150      150
Z       300     50       300
```

The problem is that the data is held in the actual dataset like stored like below because each row in the table is for a different report.

```
 X case 1   X case 2    X case 3    Y case 1    Y case 2    Y case 3    Z case 1    Z case 2    Z case 3
100         300         250         200         150         150         300         50          300
```

I've tried using the data in this format but it produces a confusing and unpleasant graph.  As this report is going to be run against all the rows of my data source I need to be able to dynamically restructure itself (or create a secondary data source) to allow this to happen.

Is this actually possible in SSRS?

Comment: Can you post what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in SQL.

**Option1**

If you can go back to the raw data that makes up the dataset you described, use that data in the format

```
[DrugName] [CaseNumber] [Value]
   X             1       100
   X             2       300
   X             3       250
   Y             1       200
   Y             2       150
   Y             3       150
   Z             1       300
   Z             2        50
   Z             3       300
```

Your chart can just the case and drug as series and category (or the other way around perhaps)

**Option2**

If you can't get to the raw data then you will have to UNPIVOT the dataset you have (I'm assuming SQL Server here..)

Look at the UNPIVOT operator

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Once you have unpivoted it into something like this...

```
[DrugCaseNum] [value]
'X Case 1'     100
'X Case 2'     200
etc...
```

then you could use this as a subquery and split the DrugCaseNum column into its constituent parts.

Comment: @AlenSchofield, ultimately I did go back and created a secondary dataset which created each line and then unioned them together. Messy but I can filter to the correct row using parameters. Though that pivot option is interesting.